# Trigger Laravel Console Command to Run Only Once

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron

I have an `artisan` command that I created and that need to be executed by my team.

`php artisan language:seed`

---

I usually place my cron tasks in my cron tab file. 
BUT Since this one is a **one time** task, I'm not sure where I should configure my command.

---

I was thinking about using Laravel migration.

Should I add that command as part of my migration script ?

```
public function up()
{
    $language = Language::where('id','=','1')->first();
    if($language == null){
        $url = shell_exec('php artisan language:seed');
    }
}
```

---

I did look into [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling) and [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/artisan), but I didn't really see what I am looking for.

Should I still add it as part of my cron task, but make sure it only run one time?

Comment: If this is part of an initial project setup, why not just create a setup.sh script in the root of the project that calls these sorts of one-time bootstrapping things?

Comment: As states @JeremyHarris, it makes sense to run that command during a setup script. You can still check the conf in your db to know if it's required to seed or you can skip that step.

Comment: This is not part of the initial set up, the project is already up, this is something new that need to be added to the project, my team members need that seeding data. Do you guys still think that setup.sh best fit my situation ? If so, I'll look into it.

Comment: @ihue So, *in that case* it makes sense to call the seeder once in an upgrade migration, as you said. So let's imagine your app needs to seed a *categories* table with new rows, this would be done once upon that new migration. But it's better if you extract the seeder code into a proper seeder and you just call it programatically from the migration class.